# Former candidate inviting the recruiter to an interview

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

A while ago I was invited to an interview at a software company. Although that was not the right place for me, the interview went very well and I was impressed by the recruiter's communication skills and her overall approach to interviewing.

Fast forward a year later, I am working for a company that is looking for a recruiter to join the team. I think that specific person is well suited for the opening and would be very valuable for the company. I could recommend her for the role, but I'm not sure what's the best approach to invite her to take that into consideration.

How should a former candidate invite the recruiter to an interview at his current company?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How should a former candidate invite the recruiter to an interview at
>   his current company?

You don't invite the recruiter directly unless the open position reports to you.

You could reach out to the recruiter, send the link for the open position, and ask if they have any interest.

But presumably your company has a HR group that is trying to fill the recruiter position.

You pass along the name and contact information of this recruiter candidate to HR, along with your good recommendation. You tell HR that they can drop your name if it will help.

And if your company offers a referral bonus, you collect the bonus if your company hires this person.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your manager or consult your company policies and see what they think, and let them guide you on company policy. I've worked for companies where we were encouraged to ask people we knew to apply for positions. They could list us as a reference if they wanted (and if we knew each other well enough), and we'd tell whoever was doing the hiring that we had referred someone which would give the hiring manager an opportunity to find out how well we knew this person and why we thought they would be a good fit.

Of course this could be different from company to company, so check with your boss (or employee manual).